# Why my Scoreboard doesn't show any result?

Tags: functional-testing, system-verilog, uvm

I'm doing some tests using System Verilog with UVM. My Scoreboard doesn't show me any result, but I cannot figure what is wrong. Any idea? The code is on the EDAPlayground, here is the link (the code can be edited there):

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/JGh

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

One big problem is the warning messages coming from the uvm_config/resource_db.
You are throwing away the result of the get() from these databases and if you a problem there, you will never see it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dave. I'm starting with SystemVerilog/UVM. I notice this warnings but I didn't know how to solve it. But if the problem can be coming from there, I'll try to solve it (any idea?), the "solution" proposed by the compiler doesn't works. But I'm thinking the problem is when I try to get() the transaction, I don't know if the way I'm tryng to do it is correct. Thanks again.

Comment: I solved the warnings! Thank you for it! Was not the compiler saying wrong things, but me doing mess. Ok, now it show none warning, but still no answers.

Answer (score 0):

I got your code working after resolving multiple issues and they are as follows:

1) In the 'my_monitor.svh', change the uvm resource db key names from "dut_if" to "dut_vif"

2) In the connect phase of your environment you seemed to have connected only one analysis port of the scoreboard. Modify as follows:
`agent.agent_ap_after.connect(sa_sb.sb_export_after); // This line was missing
agent.agent_ap_before.connect(sa_sb.sb_export_before);`

3) In your scoreboard, you seemed to have created transaction objects (using new() method) namely 'transaction_before' and 'transaction_after'. You don't really need this since the analysis port get() method will give you a populated transaction object itself. So you can remove the creation of these two objects in the scoreboard's constructor.

4) The run_phase implementation of 'my_monitor' class is empty. This class has the analysis port 'mon_ap_before' which is connected to your scoreboard's 'before_fifo'. Since nobody is writing to this monitor's analysis port, the following line in your scoreboard will never unblock:
`before_fifo.get(transaction_before); //Will never come out of this statement`
 So add some logic in your monitor as per your needs.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Sundar, really helps me a lot! Really thank you by your comment. I've fixed all the things that you wrote about the code, and it was very useful. For example, I didn't see that I will be stuck on fifo. After making all this 4 changes, I started to receive the following message:

Comment: "Error-[NOA] Null object access
scoreboard.svh, 42
  The object at dereference depth 1 is being used before it was 
  constructed/allocated.
  Please make sure that the object is allocated before using it."
It seems like I need to 'initialize' the content of these objects of my test:

if(transaction_before.out_operando == transaction_after.out_operando) begin

The error shows in this line, any idea why? Thanks once more

Comment: try doing a sprint() of the 'transaction_before' and 'transaction_after' variables after the get() call on the fifos in your scoreboard. Most likely the objects you are passing from the monitor is NULL (empty) and hence the error. Also try doing a sprint() on the objects inside the monitors as well before analysis port write().. make sure you pass valid transactions (non-empty) from the monitors..

Comment: Sundar, was that! The problem from NULL was solved. I didn't instatiate the transaction in the monitor, so it was giving me that error. I'm very greatful for your help! Now I have a return on the Scoreboard, it shows me a fail or a ok. The problem now is that it shows me just for one value, so I think it's still a problem with the value that came from the monitor. To solve the problem of null, I did:

  sa_tx = my_transaction::type_id::create
   (.name("sa_tx"), .contxt(get_full_name()));

on the run method of my monitor. Could you give me an idea from what can be?

Comment: Just creating a new transaction in monitor and sending it to the scoreboard is not correct. You need to construct a transaction in the monitor by sampling the signals on the interface (dut_vif) based on the protocol you are using and only then your compare routine will make sense. There are lots of tutorials and working examples available open source in `https://verificationacademy.com/` and `www.testbench.in`